# a CW-complex homotopic to a manifold

Tags: at.algebraic-topology, gt.geometric-topology

I'm reading a paper and here the authors say that a connected 4-manifold with zero rational top homology has a homotopy type of 3-dimensional CW-structure. I can't figure out how it can be done.

Comment: For this to be true, you need to assume that your 4-manifold is orientable.  Assuming this, your conditions imply that your 4-manifold is not compact (otherwise the 4th homology group would be Q).  It is a general fact that smooth noncompact $n$-manifolds are homotopy equivalent to $(n-1)$-dimensional CW complexes.  For details, see Mohan Ramachandran's answer to my question here : http://mathoverflow.net/questions/18454/

Comment: Consider $M=RP^4$ (or any other non-orientable closed 4-manifold). It has $H_4(M;\mathbb Q)=0$, but $H_4(M,\mathbb Z/2)\ne 0$, hence it is not homotopy equivalent to a 3-dimensional CW-complex.



Comment: @Andy @Sergei Could someone post an answer so that the question gets closed?

Comment: Sure Greg, I'll make it into an answer.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

For this to be true, you need to assume that your $4$-manifold $M$ is not a compact nonorientable manifold.  Otherwise, you would have $H_4(M;\mathbb{Q}) = 0$ but $H_4(M;\mathbb{Z}/2) \neq 0$, so there is no hope that your manifold is homotopy equivalent to a $3$-dimensional CW-complex.

Assuming this, your conditions imply that your $4$-manifold is not compact (otherwise the 4th homology group would be $\mathbb{Q}$). It is a general fact that smooth noncompact $n$-manifolds are homotopy equivalent to $(n−1)$-dimensional CW complexes. For details, see Mohan Ramachandran's answer to my question 
[here](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/18454).